# Switch data template based on value of bound data in Silverlight / WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, datatemplate

say I am using WPF or Silverlight and binding a ContentPresenter to an integer property:

```
<ContentPresenter Content={Binding Score} />
```

and if the score is 10 I want to display a gold star, and otherwise just display the number. So essentially I have two possible data templates:

```
<Path Fill="Gold" Data="..." />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}" />
```

What is the best way to set this up? Is it to use a Binding Converter? Or bind to a different object that dynamically loads the appropriate data template xaml and makes the correct FrameworkElement depending on the value of Score? Or is there another trick I am missing - perhaps ContentPresenter isn't the right control to be using?

I wondered if you could do something like this, but it doesn't like the nested binding within the ContentTemplate value:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LowScore">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Score}" Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HighScore">
            <Path Fill="Gold" Data="M 0,0 l 10,0 l 5,-10 l 5,10 l 10,0 l -7,10 l 2,10 l -10,-5 l -10,5 l 2,-10 Z" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Score}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey={Binding ScoreTemplate}}">
    </ContentPresenter>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: hi Mark Heath , nice question but realy no answer , please let me know if you figured it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could use a template selector. [Here is a nice tutorial on Switch On The Code](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector).  Basically, a template selector allows you to select the template for an item based on whatever conditions you want.

Comment: very helpful tutorial. I somehow missed out on `DataTemplateSelector`

Comment: yeah, the dts is also really nice for things like templating list items

Comment: Perfect example of why link only answers are frowned upon on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Create a DataTemplate with a StackPanel containing both control types and bind their Visibility (or use a DataTrigger) so that only one is visible at a time.  This is fairly simple and can be good if there are not many states or the differences are small.
2. Use a DataTemplateSelector and look up the DataTemplate by resource.